# Query para la hoja de calculo de google

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-query-language

Estoy haciendo una query para la hoja de calculo de google, pero cuando en el where le indico una celdade la hoja, me da error.

La query que tengo es:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("enlace"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6='"B1"' and 
Col8='"B2"'")
```

Tengo que decir que las celdas B1 y B2 provienen de una validacion de datos. Ademas, Col6 y Col8 pueden tener que seleccionar todo y tampoco se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Solo he añadido & y ha funcionado
`=query(IMPORTRANGE("enlace"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6='"&B1&"' and 
Col8='"&B2&"'")`

Comment: y qué hace el `&`?

Comment: @RuslanLópez el `&` es el operador equivalente a la función [CONCAT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592?hl=es)

Comment: Y por qué no agregas esa explicación en la respuesta?